# what to read parent xml by giving child value in .net

Tags: c#

xml:

```
<PrimaryLink>
  <LinkID>p1</LinkID>
    <SecondaryLink>
      <LinkID>s1</LinkID>      
        <LeftMenu>
          <NavLinks>
            <LinkID>n1</LinkID>
          </NavLinks>
          <NavLinks>
            <LinkID>n2 </LinkID>               
          </NavLinks>
        </LeftMenu>
    </SecondaryLink>  
</PrimaryLink>
```

c#:

```
var menuItems1 = from c in xMenuElement.Elements("GlobalNavigation").Elements("PrimaryLink")
                 select c;
```

i what the ans like p1->s1->n1 by giving n1 as input

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty unclear, but I *think* you want something like:

```
var query = xml.Descendants("LinkID")
               .Where(x => (string) x == "n1")
               .Single()
               .AncestorsAndSelf("LinkID")
               .Reverse()
               .Select(x => (string) x);
```

That will return a sequence of "p1", "s1" and "n1".

Comment: You can use the method `AncestorsAndSelf()` instead of `Ancestors()` to include last LinkID.

Comment: @Elian: I looked for that, but didn't see it. Looks like I was looking at the wrong class to find it - Ancestors is in XNode, AncestorsAndSelf is in XElement.